# Can any one suggest me why datetimepicker gives an error in data retrieve?

Tags: c#

```
string querySql = "Select Admission_Date,Name,Father_name,Date_of_birth,NIC_No,Present_Adress,Age,Contact_No,Weight,Height,Image from Admform WHERE Member_ID=@memid";

using (SqlConnection conSql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=azeem;Initial Catalog=ittihadgym;Integrated Security=True"))
{
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querySql, conSql))
   {
       conSql.Open();
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memid", textBoxmember.Text);
       SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
       if (reader.Read())
       {
          dateTimePicker1.Value=reader[0].ToString();
          textBoxname.Text = reader[1].ToString();
          textBoxfname.Text = reader[2].ToString();
          dateTimePicker2.Value=reader[3].ToString();
          textBoxnic.Text = reader[4].ToString();
          textBoxadress.Text=reader[5].ToString();
          textBoxage.Text=reader[6].ToString();
          textBoxcntct.Text=reader[7].ToString();
          textBoxweight.Text=reader[8].ToString();
          textBoxheight.Text=reader[9].ToString();

          byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[10]); 
          if (img == null)
             pictureBox1.Image = null;
          else
          {
             MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
             pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
          }
       }
       else
       {
          MessageBox.Show("This is does not exist.");
           cn.Close();
```

Comment: What error do you get and where?

Comment: datetimepicker1,value=reader[0].Tostring();
here m getting error of code

Comment: __What is the error??__

Comment: Please try to learn basic first. You have to convert it to datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);
dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[3]);
```

because it `DateTimePicker.Value` property sets or gets and the selected `DateTime`. Thus it needs a `DateTime` instead of `string`.

Comment: you both are awesome :) thnks..my code is working fine now

Comment: specially thank for giving extra information of date

Comment: Happy to help @mynameiskhan. BTW another way of saying thanks on SO could be you can upvote and if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.